# How to use the Spark SQL broadcast function

Tags: apache-spark

Spark SQL provides a function `broadcast` to indicate that the dataset is smaller enough and should be broadcast

```
def broadcast[T](df: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T] = {
  Dataset[T](df.sparkSession,
      ResolvedHint(df.logicalPlan, HintInfo(broadcast = true)))(df.exprEnc)
}
```

I know I could use it in the following way:

```
val a = spark.range(100).as("a")
val b = spark.range(100).as("b")
val df = a.join(broadcast(b)).where($"a.id" === $"b.id")
```

I want to use it in the SQL statement like:

```
spark.range(100).createOrReplaceTempView("a")
spark.range(100).createOrReplaceTempView("b")

val df = spark.sql("select a.id, c.id from a join broadcast(b)  c on a.id = c.id")
```

But it throws an exception:

```
cannot resolve '`b`' given input columns: []
```

It looks that SQL treats `b` like a column? I would ask how I can use the `broadcast` function in SQL statement.

Comment: `broadcast(b)` accepts and returns a DataSet. It is not a SQL function that accepts a column

Comment: yes...that means, broadcast is not normal function like others takes column as input, like abs etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for SQL, `select /*+ BROADCASTJOIN(b) */a.id, b.id from a join b on a.id = b.id` works to indicate dataset b to be broadcast.

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html

Comment: The exact link https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hint-framework.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple working code for your case would be

```
val a = spark.range(100).as("a")
val b = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(spark.range(100).as("b"))
val df = a.join(b.value, Seq("id"))
```

Where *SparkContext's broadcast function* is used which is defined as

> > Broadcast a read-only variable to the cluster, returning a
> >     [[org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast]] object for reading it in distributed functions.
> >     The variable will be sent to each cluster only once.
> >     @param value value to broadcast to the Spark nodes
> >     @return `Broadcast` object, a read-only variable cached on each machine